# How can i create fact table in pentaho from dim tables?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have created all my dim tables, they are very simple, Each dim table has only two fields one is PK id, another field names. So, what is the best approach to create and populate data in fact table from dim tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the results you are trying to achieve.
For instance for Fact_Sales table you would probably need date_id,store_id,product_id,units_sold

From Dim_date,Dim_Store,Dim_Product. Which have relevant additional fields on those dimension tables.

You would have to write the query based on the result what you are looking for to insert into Fact Tables.